# QSqlQuery INSERT statement with sqlite3

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

This query doesn't execute, I can't see where I did wrong in it

```
QSqlQuery query(QString("INSERT INTO [main].[sell_log] (cart_id, title, price, amount, disscount, type, total, bill_number, whos, when) "
                    "VALUES ('%1', '%2', '%3', '%4', '%5', '%6', '%7', '%8', '%9', '%10')").arg(cart_id).arg(title).arg(price).arg(amount).arg(disscount)
                    .arg(type).arg(total).arg(bill_number).arg(whos).arg(when));
    qDebug() << query.lastQuery();
    qDebug() << query.executedQuery();
```

output:

```
"INSERT INTO [main].[sell_log] (cart_id, title, price, amount, disscount, type, total, bill_number, whos, when) VALUES ('5', 'جديد', '7', '1', '0', 'سعر البيع', '7', '151', '1', '23-10-2016')"
""
```

Comment: Use `query.lastError()` to understand the error

Comment: @Fabio , i got compile error : `error: C2027: use of undefined type 'QSqlError' , see declaration of 'QSqlError'`, anyway i've used this fucntion alot of times on `SELECT` statment and it work , but in `INSERT` statment i think it's not work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved :

```
QSqlQuery query(QString("INSERT INTO [main].[sell_log] (cart_id, title, price, amount, disscount, type, total, bill_number, whos, 'when') "
```

problem was with "when", cuz the when is sql statement , so iwas need to escape